# reg ex for searching filenames

Tags: python, regex

I want to select the files, whose names ends with `_90.jpeg|_180.jpeg|_270.jpeg|_90.jpg|_180.jpg|_270.jpg`.

currently I am using the following approach

```py
pattern = re.compile('_90.jpeg|_180.jpeg|_270.jpeg|_90.jpg|_180.jpg|_270.jpg')
pattern.search(filename)
```

Is there any cleaner way to represent the _xxx.yyyy in regular expression.

Comment: Your regex contains an unescaped `.` that matches any char but line break chars and since there is no `$` at the end, the pattern matches anywhere in the string. It is not quite clear: do you plan to match a `_` + `DIGITS` + `.` + `jpe?g`  + `<EOS>` pattern? Or a specific set of numbers?

Comment: I quite new to regex. can you give explanation for what is unescaped? and ya, I will add `$` at the end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:
`pattern = re.compile('(_9|_18|_27)0\.jpe?g$')`

If any digits are fine:
`pattern = re.compile('_\d+\.jpe?g$')`

Comment: You can move the *0* out of the paren :).

Comment: Or even `_(9|18|27)0\.jpe?g$` if we want to golf it even more, but we might be starting to lose reability. (Note, you need to escape the `.`)

Comment: Your `_\d+.jpe?g$` and `(_9|_18|_27)0.jpe?g$` patterns are wrong since they match `_90§jpeg`, too.